# What does " be upon mental" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does " be upon mental" mean?
For example in this sentence:

> "we Both must be upon our mental".

Is it somehow about being crazy?

It's a story in verse; it refers to Grimm's Fairy Tales.

> Rock: 
>   We both must be upon our mental
>   she may think I'm hansel, you are Gretel"

Comment: I don't see any dictionary entries for "*mental*" as a noun, only an adjective, so I'd expect a noun to follow "*mental*", as in "*mental health*", "*mental illness*", "*mental state*", etc.  Can you quote the longer passage this appears in? (I note that in the current quote, "*Both*" is capitalized and "*we*", which starts the sentence, isn't; which leads me to believe you've edited it a bit -- can you post the quote in its original format, verbatim?)

Comment: Probably just a way of making something rhyme (just!) with _Gretel_. I would take it to mean “we both have to keep our wits about us”, but it’s quite an awkward phrasing.

Comment: It's not *mental,* it's [*mettle*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mettle#mettle__6) -- which rhymes with Gretel.

Comment: That is, [in this book](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6QFNBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT37&lpg=PT37) it's a misspelling.

Comment: Alternatively, the author could have written " We both must be upon our mental. She may think I'm Beowulf, you are Grendel."

Answer (score 1):

I could find only one instance of similar phrasing in a Google search. From Fashawn, featuring Exile, "[Bo Jackson](http://genius.com/Fashawn-bo-jackson-lyrics)," on *Boy Meets World* (2009):

> Light an incense/ My million dollar windpipe expensive/ I rip mics intensive/ The nigga they like to mention/ Alias ‘Fashawn’, government is confidential/ I’m type essential/ **Be upon my mental**, strike the pencil/ And in the notebook, there go a hundred jabs/ No hook - Don’t need a punchline/ I kick the shit to make you unwind

From this extract, it appears that to "be upon [one's] mental" is to be alert and thinking clearly. Unfortunately, the Fashawn example doesn't corroborate the example in the OP's original quotation because—as Andrew Leach points out in a comment above—(a) the word in the OP's text is *metal*, not *mental*, and (b) the word *metal* there seems to be a misrendering of the homophone *mettle*. Here is the relevant portion of Alan Ayckbourn, [*The Boy Who Fell into a Book*](https://books.google.com/books?id=6QFNBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT37&lpg=PT37&dq=%22+We+both+must+be+upon+our+metal%22&source=bl&ots=DZxcSFGKvC&sig=tAH9p0BaScybrFLdYx2GFqxHG00&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6hJq-_6jPAhUQ92MKHYvOD-sQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22%20We%20both%20must%20be%20upon%20our%20metal%22&f=false) (2000):

> **Woman:** You will not need a map or charts/ To find your way around these parts./ Be back before you count to ten — (*She makes to leave.*)/ Whoops! That's the cupboard once again.
>
> **Rock:** I don't want you to worry, but/ I think we're trapped here with a nut.
>
> **Kevin:** I'm still trying to think what this story must be ...
>
> **Rock:** We both must **be upon our metal**/ She may think I'm Hansel, you are Gretel ...
>
> **Kevin:** It's OK, we don't have to talk like that, now.
>
> **Rock:** Oh sure, I forgot.

So "be upon my mental" in Fashawn's song appears to mean "be thinking with acuity," while "be upon our mental" in Ayckbourn's play means "be upon our mettle"—that is, "be brave."